# sqlline not showing all columns of a Ignite table on terminal

Tags: ignite, gridgain, sqlline

I've created a table in Ignite which has more than 20 columns. Now, on sqlline I can only see five columns of that table out of 20 columns when query the data like "select * from table_name". Is there any way to do that in sqlline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following sqlline command:

```
!set maxWidth 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL line can't show so many columns horizontally properly, so you can use vertical mode:

```
!outputformat vertical
```

Comment: I've already checked vertical mode but it's not giving output in proper tabular format.